# How to update a Control (TextBlock) from inside a static method

Tags: c#, wpf, object, static

I've read the other threads on the subject but I'm having no joy.

I'm trying to update the content of my wpf TextBlock from inside a static method **UpdateTextBlock**, this method needs to be static as I'm calling it from inside a Timer and it'll only work for some reason if it is static.

```
public static void UpdateTextBlock()
{
            foreach (String s in GetWhoList())
            {
                TextBlock1.Inlines.Add(s);
            }
}
```

Basically need to find a way to reference TextBlock1 to the object that it appears in I think. Struggling to get my head around the methodology of it. I understand that it doesnt know what to reference because it's static, but not sure the commands to tie it to the TextBlock in my Windows App.

I'm generating error code **CS0120**

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MainWindow.TextBlock1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static property that contains TextBlock1's control. TextBlock1's window can initialize it, for example, in the "loaded" event or anywhere else you think is right.
Consider removing static modifier from the method that works with non-static objects instead.

Comment: Thanks Farhad, would you be able to write an example of that?

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't have much time now. But it's simple if you can do it in no time.